# what happen if I change my Repository from GitHub to Bitbucket but my app is on Heroku

Tags: github, heroku, bitbucket

I hosted my Django app In Heroku using github, but now I want to change my repository from github to BitBucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your application from GitHub to Bitbucket shouldn't cause it to be removed from Heroku.

If you are using [GitHub integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration), that will break. You won't get automatic deploys when you push to Bitbucket. But even if you remove your GitHub repository, the running app on Heroku should remain functional.

If you've connected your GitHub account to Heroku I suggest [disconnecting it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#disconnecting-from-github).

[Git deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) has no knowledge of other remotes you might have configured, so it will be unaffected by this move. You'll just have to make sure you have a remote for Bitbucket and a remote for Heroku, and push to the right one.